# How to geocode with TurfJS with lat/long?

Tags: javascript, geocode, turfjs

How can I get the location details / geocode with TurfJS? I want to simply give it a lat/long and get back the country, state, zipcode, etc...

I checked their online documentation but didn't see a clear way to do this...?

Something like below...

```
const turf = require("@turf/turf")

const lat = 51.50998

const long = -0.13375

const details = turf.geocode(lat,long)

console.log(details)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't possible within Turf. Closest you could probably get is having the state geometries on hand, and doing a [booleanPointInPolygon](https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointInPolygon).

But really, you're looking for something more like the [Mapbox geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/)

Answer (score 1):

In case you only need the country information based on coords, you can use the [coordinate_to_country](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coordinate_to_country) npm package. This way you don't need any API.

**EDIT:**

It worth to note that the **[coordinate_to_country](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coordinate_to_country)** npm package is quite heavy, causing a efficiency issues on the client-side. This is due to the ~50Mb geojson file in the [@osm_borders/maritime_10m](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@osm_borders/maritime_10m?activeTab=readme) dependent package.

Therefore, if you don't need all countries included in your coordinates lookup, you are better off using [geojson-geometries-lookup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-geometries-lookup) npm package and a custom geojson file of the countries you need.

Another alternative is use a lower resolution country shapes file to reduce file size - this can compromise accuracy.

Here is a site to download custom selection of geojson country shapes: https://osm-boundaries.com/

---

Otherwise, if you need more location information (city, address, neighbourhood etc.) you can explore various geocoding API's such as:

- [OSM - Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/)
- [Mapbox Geocoding](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/)
- [Google Maps Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)
- [OpenCage Geocoding](https://opencagedata.com/api#quickstart)
- [Tomtom Geocoding](https://developer.tomtom.com/geocoding-api/documentation/geocode)